# Finding a Retraction for a Collar Neighborhood

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, manifolds-with-boundary

In Hirsch, pp.113-114 there is a proof that in a manifold with boundary $M$, $\partial M$ has a collar neighborhood. I attach it here:

[image]

I am not sure how he is gluing together two local retractions into coordinate domains with a bump function. I was wondering if someone would be able to help me here.