# Consequences of the Globalization Theorem in Hirsch's Differential Topology

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, sheaf-theory, functors

In Hirsch's book, there is a wonderful theorem 2.11:

[image]

where a structure functor is simply a presheaf, and continuous means it is a sheaf (it has the gluing property). Nontrivial means there is at least one local section.

Locally extendable means, in his words:

[image]

As an example, if $X$ is a $C^r$ manifold, and if $\mathfrak{F}(Y), Y\subseteq X$ is the set of compatible $C^s$ differential structures on $Y$, $1\leq r <s \leq \infty$, then $(\mathfrak{F}, \mathfrak{U})$ ($\mathfrak{U}$ the open sets of $X$) form a nontrivial, continuous, locally extendable structure functor.

My question is: how can we use this technique to the problem of [Finding a Retraction for a Collar Neighborhood](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318657/finding-a-retraction-for-a-collar-neighborhood)? I copy the relevant excerpt:

[image]